PhpUnit - assert test duration for performance tests?
The project I'm working on has a couple of "batch operations", i.e. the application takes a bunch of data instances and run the same operation on all of them.
Our unit tests covers operation input, output, etc, but we would like to measure the application performance on a (nearly) real use case: we would like to run the operation on e.g. 10, 100, and 1000 data instances and measure its execution time to evaluate its performance.
Being able to define lower and upper boundaries like line coverage would be perfect:
public function test_it_doesnt_take_too_long()
{
    $this->startMeasuring();

    // run business logic

    $this->assertDuration($lower, $higher);
}

